# Images losing quality in browser preview

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

As you can see, my problem is with the browser preview of images.

[image: preview]

Attached is an original image and the screenshot of the browser preview from my website.

My code used to display the image is:

HTML

```
<div class="pricebox col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-ss-12">
    <img src="assets/img/preturi/aerobic-nelimitat.png" class="img-pricebox img-responsive" alt=""/>
</div>`
```

CSS

```
.pricebox {margin-bottom:35px;}
.img-pricebox {width:100%; height:auto;}
```

The dimensions of images are 550px x 200px arranged in col-6 grid, enough to any display I think.

What can I do to improove the quality? Any CSS solution, maybe a specific Photoshop rendering configuration?

PS: Also, the local preview from my attachement lose a little bit of quality.

Comment: The only difference i see is the light gray border in the browser preview. Is there any other difference i should see ?

Comment: the second image is a not crisp and the text is blurry a little

Comment: Yes, that little texts are mare gray also, like with some opacity aplied.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the max-width of an image to100% could actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> 550px x 200px arranged in col-6 grid, enough to any display I think

For screen resolution `1366` as width, I don't think `550px` for `col-6` is enough, so better to use a little higher resolution like `700px` width and check it again

Comment: You welcome, please let's know if it worked, hopefully it will